# jQuery - altering HTML using remove or replaceWith

Tags: jquery, html

I need to alter some HTML using jQuery - (I have no control over the HTML hence I need to use something client side to make this slight alteration)

If a `<br />` is the first element in a div named 'column', then I need to remove it.

So:

```
<div class="column">
   <br />text here lorem ipsum blah<br />
```

Would become:

```
<div class="column">
   text here lorem ipsum blah<br />
```

Note, I don't want to get rid of all the `<br />` tags, only if a `<br />` tag directly follows the opening  tag.

I had hoped something like this would work, but no joy

```
$('<div class="column"><br />').replaceWith('<div class="column">');
```

Any help appreciated! Many thanks!

Comment: You could try the `:first-child` selector to get your starting `br`s. http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/

Comment: Not going to enter the downvote war, but [what about using `.filter`](http://jsfiddle.net/eQnNJ/) to take care of non-empty leading text nodes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should do it :

```
var pattern = /^<br\/>/;
$("<div.column").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        text = $this.text();
    if(text.match(pattern)) {
        $this.text(text.replace('<br/>', ''))
    }
});
```

*(ignore - left in place so as to make sense of comments below)*

### EDIT

Try this :

```
var pattern = /^\n*\s*<br>/;
$("div.column").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        html = $this.html();
    if(html.match(pattern)) {
        $this.html(html.replace(pattern, ''))
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KLWtt/)**

As @minitech points out, any event handlers and data attached to the original HTML will be lost, so either :

- do the replacement before attaching any event handlers/data
- take measures to re-instantiate event handlers/data after replacement
- delegate event handling to the container element
- do something completely different that is non-destructive -  see @minitech's answer.

### Second EDIT

After much playing, at last something concise. Try this near 100% jQuery version of @minitech's approach :

```
$('.column').each(function() {
    $.each(this.childNodes, function(i, c) {
        return !$(c).filter('br').remove().end().text().trim(); 
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7x5vs/)**

Explanation: The inner loop visits each childNode in turn; its single statement removes the current node if it is a `<br>` but allows the loop to progress only if the current node is blank or whitespace. Note judicious use of `.end()` to keep everything in one method chain.

Efficiency: Poor - that jQuery method chain must consume a few CPU cycles but that seems a small price to pay.

Readabiity: Close to nada.

### Third EDIT

With a mild mod, this will handle any combination of leading whitespace/BRs/HTML comments :

```
$('.column').each(function() {
    $(this.childNodes).each(function(i, c) {
        return !$(c).filter('br').remove().end().text().trim(); 
    });
});
```

The difference from the last version is that the jQuery object `$(this.childNodes)` remains unaffected by node removal, whereas the raw `this.childNodes` is affected and the `.each()` loop doesn't scan properly. At least, that's my best attempt at an explanation.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7x5vs/2/)**

Comment: I like where this is going but with the current code, wouldn't this replace all br tags in that column?

Comment: It's OK. `.replace()` as used here will only replace the first instance.

Comment: This won't quite do it; there's whitespace at the start. Plus, the `<br/>` is not actually guaranteed to appear in that form.

Comment: Agreed  @minitech, it needs some development.

Comment: I am not good with regular expressions but you can add the detection for space in it can't you?

Comment: Also, `text()` isn't the one you're looking for. It should be `html()`. (Even then, it's important to note that all the elements within will lose their event handlers, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Raw node manipulations!

```
$('.column').each(function() {
    var firstChild = this.firstChild;

    while(firstChild && (firstChild.nodeType === 3 && /^\s*$/.test(firstChild.nodeValue) || firstChild.nodeType === 8)) {
        firstChild = firstChild.nextSibling;
    }

    if(firstChild && firstChild.nodeName === 'BR') {
        this.removeChild(firstChild);
    }
});​
```

[Here's a demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/AxJTz/1/)

Comment: Wrong. This code works good but not perfectly. For eg. this code skips colums with content like: `<!-- ss --><br>2 bla bla bla...<br />` or `&#160;<br>2 bla bla bla...<br />...`

Comment: @ViliusGaidelis: As it should; a non-breaking space is called non-breaking for a reason.

Comment: @ViliusGaidelis: Oops, I missed the "comment" part of your comment :D It's fixed now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

how about removing it if it's at the first location?

```
var relevantDiv = $('#someDiv');
var divHtml = relevantDiv.html();
if ($.trim(divHtml).indexOf('<br') == 0)
{
    relevantDiv.html(divHtml.substr(divHtml.indexOf('>')+1));
}
```

Takes care of all sort of br tags and whitespace in the beginning.

Comment: That's really, really, really inefficient.

Comment: Yea, it's a brute force solution for a general tiny problem. Dunno what's the use for it, not stated

Comment: That's not what I'm talking about... you query for `$('#someDiv')` three times and use inefficient HTML modifications. Cache something, at least! :)

Comment: should also check for <br> or just check for <br and cut it off at the next >

Comment: This won't work, though, because there's whitespace at the start of the HTML (indentation).

Comment: Would the html() return the white space as well? I have never tried

Comment: How about this edit? added trim, and remove till the end of the br

Comment: `trim` is not a standalone function; did you mean `$.trim()`? (Also, it may be important to note that any elements within will lose their event handlers, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$("div.column").each(function(){
    var ws=true;
    $(this).contents().filter(function(){
        if (this.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'br' && ws){
            ws = false;
            return true;
        }
        ws &= $.trim($(this).text()) === "" && this.nodeName === "#text";
        return false;
    }).remove();
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bnWM7/1/

Answer (score -1):

How about this guys:

```
var br = $("div.column br:first-child");

if(br.length > 0 && br[0].previousSibling == null)
{
    br.remove();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zeDn3/3/

Comment: Still won't work if there's leading whitespace, which there is (but I didn't downvote you).

Comment: I won't :D I think it maybe helpful to somebody

Answer (score -2):

Try something like this:

```
    var content = $('div.column').html();
    // there remove <br /> from content if it exits
    $('div.column').empty().append(content);
```

Comment: I think you need to provide a couple details there.

Comment: minitech, do you mean I should provide how to remove the first br tag in the string? var cell_content = "<br />text here lorem ipsum blah<br />"; var new_cell_content = cell_content.replace(/^\s*<br\s*\/>/,""); alert(new_cell_content);

Comment: Yes, that's the entire point of the question. Anybody can get and set the HTML content. (In fact, `.html()` would be preferable over `.empty().append()` here.)

Comment: var cell_content = "<br />text here lorem ipsum blah<br />";
var new_cell_content = cell_content.replace(/^\s*<br\s*\/>/,"");
alert(new_cell_content);

Comment: That won't work, the `/` seems not to be included in the returned HTML. Anyway, somebody already answered with a little more effort about an hour ago.

Comment: What not work?? my provided code works correctly. the first <br /> tag is removed from the string in variable new_cell_content .

Comment: The question is about <br /> . In general, it can be many options: <br>, <br class="someclass">,  or something else... But the question is about <br /> so my answer is corresponding.

Comment: Wrong. This is a direct product of you not actually trying anything.